# Is there a way to embed widgets in or aligned with a generated HTML table?

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app that does an ANOVA and outputs it to a nicely formatted HTML table. I  would like to have a column of the table with checkboxes that will indicate if that effect is to be pooled.

The length of the table will change based on the user's data and design.

I can dynamically create the checkboxes, I just can't figure out how to either align them with the table or better yet embed them within the table.

From the MRE, here is what I would like:

[image: Move checkboxes into table]

```
#test for embedding widget in HTML table
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "lines",label = "Lines of Data",min = 1,max = 272,value = 10,step = 1),
  uiOutput("html_table"),
  uiOutput("box_out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$html_table<-renderUI({
      rows<-input$lines
      data<-faithful[1:rows,]
      table<-c("<table><tr><th>Eruptions</th><th>Waiting</th><th>Checkbox</th></tr>")
      for(i in 1:rows){
        table<-c(table,"<tr><td>",data[i,1],"</td><td>",data[i,2],"</td><td>CB here</td></tr>")
      }
      table<-HTML(c(table,"</table>"))
      table
    })
    
    makeBox<-function(n){
      checkboxInput(inputId = paste0("check",n),label = paste0("Box",n),value = FALSE)
    }
    
    widgetVector<-reactive({
      num_box<-input$lines
      lapply(X = 1:num_box,FUN=makeBox)
    })
    
    output$box_out<-renderUI({
      tagList(widgetVector())
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `HTML` for the checkboxes directly in your table definition, see the example below.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sliderInput(inputId = "lines",label = "Lines of Data",min = 1,max = 272,value = 10,step = 1),
    uiOutput("html_table"),
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .checkbox {
                        margin-top: 5px;
                        margin-bottom: 5px;
                    }
                    ")
               )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$html_table<-renderUI({
        rows<-input$lines
        data<-faithful[1:rows,]
        table<-c("<table><tr><th>Eruptions</th><th>Waiting</th><th>Checkbox</th></tr>")
        for(i in 1:rows){
            table<-c(table,"<tr><td>",data[i,1],"</td><td>",data[i,2], paste0("</td><td>CB here</td>
                     <td> 
                        <div class = 'checkbox'> 
                            <label>
                                <input id = 'check", i, "' class = 'shiny-input-checkbox shiny-bound-input' type = 'checkbox'>
                                <span>Box", i, "</span> 
                            </label> 
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     </tr>")
            )
        }
        table<-HTML(c(table,"</table>"))
        table
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```